# What's the cleanest way code-wise to return a statically sized array from an object?

Tags: c++

I have a situation where a class holds a vector of constant size 5.  I need the data from the vector as an array of size 5 as our std::vector implementation doesn't appear to use contiguous memory (please don't argue about that, I know it should and we've checked it to death).  The contiguous memory block is required so we can uuencode/uudecode the memory block easily (those turn an arbitrary memory block into a string).

I'm finding it difficult to return a statically sized array.  I can do it by reference or I can do it by wrapping a statically sized array in a structure - but both are a little agitating.  By reference requires the calling code to declare the array first and pass it in to the code, and the other option requires that I make an extra structure just for this purpose.

```
class A {
    public:
        /*return type*/ GetVectorAsArray(/*params*/) { /* implementation */ }

    private:
        std::vector<X> m_vec;
};
```

So, assuming I need to call GetVectorAsArray, what's the cleanest way to return the 5 values in m_vec to the calling code?  You can put whatever you want in return type or params and implementation.

Comment: I know you've said not to argue about it, but a vector by definition should be holding elements in contiguous memory.  What STL implementation are you using so I know to avoid it in the future?

Comment: If its size is always five, why not use a C-style array?

Comment: What is ok to use? Boost? C++11? Anything else?

Comment: Maybe padding is causing the issue with contiguous memory. For example, maybe `sizeof(X)` == 7. I think that objects are usually 8-aligned or something like that.

Comment: Preferably straight C++, and @Chad - I'm well aware, we're on a proprietary OS called lynxos - its a unix-like variant and apparently a little different than it should be :p

Comment: @w00te LynxOS uses GNU toolchain and gcc's implementation of vector is fine, at least in my LynxOS 4.0.0 (gcc 2.95.3, vector is stored as three pointers: start, finish, end_of_storage)

Comment: Maybe I had a misconception then.  The vector has good data but when copied using memcpy(dest, &mvec[0], 5*sizeof(contents)) the dest ended up being jibberish after the first contents value.  using std::copy on that same vector with iterators yielded the desired result though.

Comment: @w00te: Interesting you say you prefer straight C++, then `memcpy`. :) We have copy-constructors for a reason, you were probably invalidating the data by copying the bits rather than the 'object'. Never treat anything like a array of bits in C++, unless it's definitely a POD type.

Comment: @w00te: GMan raises a good point.  What type is X in `std::vector<X>`?

Comment: Sorry, by straight C++ I meant the standard library contents, not C++ over C.  The type inside the vector was a struct containing normal scalars, no strings, and no pointers.  POD always confuses me, but it was contiguous and memcpy-able when it was an array instead of a vector (other places in the code). Sorry for quick answer leaving for train :) I'll check back later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/array.html) is intended for arrays of fixed size, you can always use that. It uses contiguous memory.

Later edit: as correctly pointed out by commenters, std::array is available in the new standard.

Comment: Note that its now part of C++ Standard Library as of TR1

Comment: Nowadays that's also available as `std::array`.

Comment: it is indeed, just making sure there's an answer for people not having access to the new standard.

Comment: And if neither is available, just a normal C-style array is fine.

Comment: @GMan: You can't return C-style arrays by value. The OP didn't specify whether he wanted a copy or the original...

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename X, size_t N>
class A {
private:
  X m_vec[N];
public:
  const X* GetVectorAsArray() const { return m_vec; }
  size_t GetVectorLength() const { return N; }
};
```

Usage:

```
A<int, 5> vec5_int;
```